# Getting [Function: toBSON] and {} when console logging an array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to figure out why I am getting

`console.log(removedEvent.invitees[i])` result:

> luke231@gmail.com
>
> yoda231@gmail.com
>
> [Function: toBSON]
>
> {}
>
> ... The rest is information about removedEvent itself

But if I console log before my for loop I get the following... `console.log(removedEvent.invitees);`

> ["luke231@gmail.com","yoda231@gmail.com"]

Here is my code (disregard res headers, I know.):

```
router.delete(
  "/remove/:event_id",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    Event.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.params.event_id }).then(removedEvent => {
      console.log(removedEvent.invitees);
      for (let i in removedEvent.invitees) {
        console.log(removedEvent.invitees[i]);
        User.findOne({ email: removedEvent.invitees[i] })
          .then(user => {
            res.json(user);
          })
          .catch(err => res.json({ err }));
      }
    });
  }
```

This is throwing everything off because of me looping through my `User.findOne`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out why I was getting that output when I console.log'd, but I used `forEach()` instead of the `for` loop and it works as expected.